# How to mock response of getPass function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Hello I am writing a unit test case of my javascript function. I am using mocha, Chai, expect, sinon

app.js

```
module.exports = {
    saveInGlobal: async () => {
      try {
        if (global.pass !== null && global.pass !== '') {
          return module.exports.getpass().then((res) => {
            return global.pass = res;
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {

      }
    },
    getPass: async () => {
       return "test";
    } 
}
```

I want to mock the `getPass()` function and then assert `global.pass`. Can anyone suggest how to mock the `getPass()` here using `sinon`

Answer (score 0):

The basic functionality is provided by `sinon.stub()` which overrides some property in object - in your case `module.getPass`:

```
const theModule = require('theModule'); // module with getPass
it('foo', () => {
    // Prepare
    const getPassStub = sinon.stub(theModule, 'getPass');
    getPassStub.resolves('mocked');
    // Act

    // call your code here

    // Assert
    expect(getPassStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    getPassStub.restore()
});
```

This works, but only if your test passes. In case of failure, stub survives (`restore` is not called) and `getPass` remains mocked for rest of test execution.

Consider using: `after(() => module.getPass.restore())` or more preferably using `sinon.Sandbox`.

Stub doc: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.5.0/stubs/

Sandbox doc: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.5.0/sandbox/

Comment: I am getting an error `module.exports.getpass(...).then is not a function`

Comment: I overlooked `then`. You've got error in code as you call then on `getPass` which doesn't return promise.
Either make `getPass` async (and return Promise and use `stub.resolves(value)` on stub) or remove `then` from your target code and process this in "sync" way.

Comment: my bad, it is async. I am still getting same error `module.exports.getpass(...).then is not a function`

Comment: Please read your code carefully. You've probably mistyped `getpass` with `getPass`.

Comment: Consider using linter or better - TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `try/catch` with asynchronous code(`promise.then`). So I remove it. Here is the unit test:

`app.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  saveInGlobal: async () => {
    if (global.pass !== null && global.pass !== "") {
      return module.exports.getPass().then((res) => {
        return (global.pass = res);
      });
    }
  },
  getPass: async () => {
    return "test";
  },
};
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const app = require("./app");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("49858991", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  describe("#saveInGlobal", () => {
    it("should save in global", async () => {
      global.pass = "a";
      const getPassStub = sinon.stub(app, "getPass").resolves("mock value");
      await app.saveInGlobal();
      sinon.assert.calledOnce(getPassStub);
      expect(global.pass).to.be.eq("mock value");
    });

    it("should do nothing", async () => {
      global.pass = null;
      const getPassStub = sinon.stub(app, "getPass").resolves("mock value");
      await app.saveInGlobal();
      sinon.assert.notCalled(getPassStub);
      expect(global.pass).to.be.eq(null);
    });
  });

  describe("#getPass", () => {
    it('should return "test"', async () => {
      const actual = await app.getPass();
      expect(actual).to.be.eq("test");
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 49858991
    #saveInGlobal
      ✓ should save in global
      ✓ should do nothing
    #getPass
      ✓ should return "test"


  3 passing (16ms)

-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File         |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/49858991